# Python Pandas - dropping multiple values based on a list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop values from a dataframe that fuzzy match items in a list.

I have a dataframe (test_df) that looks like:

```
   id          email         created_at      
0  1   son@mail_a.com   2017-01-21 18:19:00  
1  2   boy@mail_b.com   2017-01-22 01:19:00  
2  3  girl@mail_c.com   2017-01-22 01:19:00
```

I have a list of a few hundred email domains that I am reading in from a txt file that looks like:

```
mail_a.com
mail_d.com
mail_e.com
```

I'm trying to drop from the dataframe any row that contains a matching email domain using:

```
email_domains = open('file.txt', 'r')
to_drop = email_domains.read().splitlines()    
dropped_df = test_df[~test_df['email'].isin(to_drop)]
    print(test_df)
```

So, the result should look like:

```
   id          email         created_at       
0  2   boy@mail_b.com   2017-01-22 01:19:00  
1  3  girl@mail_c.com   2017-01-22 01:19:00
```

But the first row with "son@mail_a.com" is not dropped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to parse domain name from the email, so we can first parse domains using `.str.split('@')` and then check it using `isin()` method:

```
In [12]: df[~df.email.str.split('@').str[1].isin(domains.domain)]
Out[12]:
   id            email           created_at
1   2   boy@mail_b.com  2017-01-22 01:19:00
2   3  girl@mail_c.com  2017-01-22 01:19:00
```

where:

```
In [13]: domains
Out[13]:
       domain
0  mail_a.com
1  mail_d.com
2  mail_e.com
```

Answer (score 3):

`isin`  looks for exact matches. Your condition is more suitable for `endswith`  or `contains`:

```
df[~df['email'].str.endswith(tuple(to_drop))]
Out: 
   id            email           created_at
1   2   boy@mail_b.com  2017-01-22 01:19:00
2   3  girl@mail_c.com  2017-01-22 01:19:00
```

---

```
df[~df['email'].str.contains('|'.join(to_drop))]
Out: 
   id            email           created_at
1   2   boy@mail_b.com  2017-01-22 01:19:00
2   3  girl@mail_c.com  2017-01-22 01:19:00
```

Comment: @MaxU Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `apply` and `split` the string and use it for your `isin`

```
print test_df[~test_df['email'].apply(lambda x: x.split('@')[1]).isin(to_drop)]
```

results in

```
            created_at            email
1  2017-01-22 01:19:00   boy@mail_b.com
2  2017-01-22 01:19:00  girl@mail_c.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer...This is a one liner:

```
exclude = ['mail_a.com','mail_d.com','mail_e.com']
df[df.apply(lambda x: all([x['email'].rfind(ex) < 0 for ex in exclude]), axis=1)]
# OUTPUT
# Out[50]:
#              created_at            email  id
# 1   2017-01-22 01:19:00   boy@mail_b.com   2
# 2   2017-01-22 01:19:00  girl@mail_c.com   3
```

Here I use the rfind returns -1 if the pattern isn't found.